# Android market URLs

Tags: android, google-play

For my new released application I use the following url to get it on the Android market

> http://market.android.com/details?id=com.kamosoft.happycontacts

From my Android device, when I click on this url, I'm well forwarded to the Market application , on my application page, that's work fine.

But from a PC with a standard browser, I got `404 Error not found` ! Why ?

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not relevant anymore since Google enabled Market access from desktop browsers (2011 Feb 02) [http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/new-merchandising-and-billing-features.html]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Android market isn't available on a standard web browser, only on a handset.

The market application specifies that it wishes to hijack market links from the browser. Take a look at the [`<data>`](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) element in intent filters to see how this is implemented.

Comment: Meanwhile google created a regular website for the market and the http://market.android.com/... urls work outside of Android as well.